# Unity3D - Bug after reloading the scene

Tags: c#, image, object, unity-game-engine, instantiation

The mobile game i'm currently creating displays the score after Game over, and reloads the level. Behind the text i'm displaying an background image prefab. The game works fine until i spawn the image.

Code:

```
    // set gameOver flag to true.
    public void GameOver()
    {
        GameoverText.text = "Game Over!";
        gameOver = true;
    }

    ......
    ......
    // Instantiate GameOverBGAsset1 -- the image prefab, and GameOverCanvas -- a reference to 'Canvas2', And make GameOverBGAsset1 a child of Canvas2.
    if (gameOver)
    {
                GameObject GameOverImg2 = Instantiate(GameOverBGAsset1, GameOverBGPos.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
                GameObject GameOverCanvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas2");
                GameOverBGAsset1.transform.SetParent(GameOverCanvas.transform);

                restartText.text = "Tap to Replay";
                scoreTextLarge.text = "Score: " + score;
                restart = true;

                break;
            } 

   ....
   ....
   // restart when screen is touched
   if (restart)
   {
               tap = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.GetTouch(0).position.x, Input.GetTouch(0).position.y, 5));            
               if ((tap.x != 0) || (tap.y != 0) || (tap.z != 0))
               {
                 Application.LoadLevel("Application.LoadedLevel");
               }
    }
```

When i reload the level it displays "Game Over!" -- coz it's displayed before i spawn the image -- and get stuck there. Is it actually a problem with the spawned prefab, or something else?

Thanks for any input.

EDIT: This ONLY happens when i reload the level. In the first run, all the intended text and BG image is displayed as expected.

Comment: Application.LoadLevel("Application.LoadedLevel");  requires the scene name as parameter.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, there's no quotes there, only Application.LoadedLevel, which loads the current level. Typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you relod scene you **restart only non-static variables**. After load scene variable GameoverText.text still contains value "Game Over!".

Comment: But GameoverText.text actually resets to "" after reloading. And my problem is that after reloading and playing, after game is over, it does not display the BG image and score.??